# After adding a user document to mongo collection; How to show that name on their profile page?

Tags: javascript, html, mongodb, express

I want a user to be able to create a profile;
then be directed to a page which shows their username.

The user registration part is working correctly:

```
app.post('/users',
    function (req, res) {
        var hashedPassword = Users.hashPassword(req.body.Password);
        Users.findOne({ Ainm: req.body.Name })
            .then(function (user) {
                if (user) {
                    return res.status(400).send(req.body.Name + "Name already in use.");
                } else {
                    Users
                        .create({
                            Name: req.body.Name,
                            Password: hashedPassword,
                            Email: req.body.Email
                        })
                        .then(function (user) {
                            res.status(201).sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "public", "profile.html"));
                        }).catch(function (error) {
                            console.error(error);
                            res.status(500).send("Error: " + error);
                        })
                }
            }).catch(function (error) {
                console.error(error);
                res.status(500).send("Error: " + error);
            });
    });
```

but can anybody suggest how to send their data from the server to the client, in order to show  user's name on the profile page to which they are being redirected?

the client side html is like this:

> ```
>     <div id="registration-menu">
>
>       <form action="/users" method="post">
>         <br />
>
>
>         <input type="text" name="Ainm"  placeholder="Ainm">
>         <br />
>
>         <input type="password" name="Password" placeholder="Passfhocal" >
>         <br />
>         <input type="email" name="Email" id="email" placeholder="seoladh r-post">
>         <br />
>         <br />
>
>         <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="defaultCheck1">
>         <label class="form-check-label" for="defaultCheck1">
>           Nuachtlitir
>         </label>
>         <br />
>
>         <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block" id="register" value="cláraigh">
>       </form>
> ```

Comment: set the user you are saving, in response and read it on client.

Comment: Thank you.
So, something like 
`Users
            .create({
              Name: req.body.Name,
              Password: hashedPassword,
              Email: req.body.Email
            })
            .then(function (user) {
              res.send(req.body.Name);
              res.sendFile('./public/profile.html', { root: __dirname })


            })`
//This doesn't work yet.
Also, sorry for dire formatting

Comment: can you share your client side code from where this request is fired?

Comment: Yep, I've added that to the question above, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ,

```js
res.redirect('/users/${req.body.Name}')
```

and setup a new route to display user details , using their names as id to figure out other details (duplicate names will cause conflict).

Comment: Thank you.
I don't quite understand.
This returns a white screen with "Unauthorized". I guess that indicates an authentication issue with mongoDb; but that's strange because I can return all the user data with res.json(user)

Comment: @RoibeárdMacUnfraidh did u make new route, like 
```app.get("/users/:userName", (req, res) => {
   //pass required details in res
})
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm trying. I evidentally have a bit more reading to do.

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery's .ajax() to send the data from clientside to server side, as previously:

> ```
> $('#btnSendMsg').click(function () {
>   $.ajax('/addMsg', {
>       type: 'POST',  // http method
>       data: { myData: usrMsg },  // data to submit
>       success: function () {
>           usrMsg = $('#output').html()
>           // alert(usrMsg)
>
>           $('#output').fadeOut();
>           setTimeout(function () {
>               $('#output').empty();
>               $('#output').fadeIn();
>
>           }, 500)
>       }
>   });
> });
> ```

The server requires a mongoose schema to liase with db. Components should have a few run-throughs implementing data storage.
Respond from server with .json representing eventual db.

```
>//client-side.js

> let gotIt = [];
> $.ajax('urlOfData', { dataType: 'json' }).then(function
> (response) {  gotIt = response;   //
> alert(JSON.stringify(response)) })
```